# Run bash alias from Apache Hive

Tags: bash, hadoop, hive

I am trying to create an alias on Hadoop machine and run it from Hive JVM.
When I explicitly run the command from Hive with ! prefix it works, however when I add the alias, source the .bashrc file and call the alias from Hive, I get an error. Example:

.bashrc content:

```
# Environment variables required by hadoop
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
export HADOOP_HOME_WARN_SUPPRESS=true
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:/home/hadoop/bin

alias load-table='java -cp /home/hadoop/userlib/MyJar.jar  com.MyClass.TableLoader';
```

Call on Hive:

```
!load-table;
```

Output:

```
Exception raised from Shell command Cannot run program "load-table": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Comment: You will have less troubles using functions instead of aliasess

Comment: you need to add alias in a different file (i think it's .bash_aliases) not inside bashrc.

Comment: @AvinashRaj That's simply not true. It might be more common to place them in `.bash_aliases` but anything in a `.bashrc` file gets executed, this includes aliases

Answer (score 1):

Aliases have several limitations compared to shell functions (e.g. by default you cannot call an alias from a non-interactive shell).

Define in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
function load-table() {
    # Make sure the java executable is accessible
    if which java > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        java -cp /home/hadoop/userlib/MyJar.jar com.MyClass.TableLoader
    else
        echo "java not found! Check your PATH!"
    fi
}
export -f load-table # to export the function (BASH specific)
```

Source you `.bashrc` to apply the changes. Then, call `load-table`.